# check if syntax in pandas column meets certain criteria

Tags: python, pandas, syntax

I have the dataframe underneath:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(['YM.296','MM.305','VO.081.019','VO.081.016','AM.081.002.001','AM081','SR.082','VO.081.012.001','VO.081.012.003']))
```

I want to know in what row the syntax is similar to 'XX.222.333' (example). So two letters followed by a stop ('.') followed by three numbers followed by a stop ('.') followed by three numbers again.

The desired outcome looks as follows:

```
tf = pd.DataFrame(np.array([False,False,True,True,False,False,False,False, False]))
```

Is there a fast and pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using `str.contains` and regex.

As follows:

```
df[0].str.contains(r'^[A-Z]{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}$', regex=True)
```

Outputs:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

Here is a visualization of the regex used:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! how does it work exactly? what does 'r' do for example? You know where I can read about it?

Comment: `r` in front of a string specify that this is a regex string. This regular expression specify your code convention. It will match codes that start with 2 capitalized letters, point then 3 digits, point and end up with 3 digits.

Comment: I added an image so you can better understand the regex used. Additionally, here is a good website to learn regular expression: https://regexone.com/.

Comment: Thanks! Will definitely take a look. I have one thing to add that I forgot. It is also possible that the syntax is ''XX.222.333. 444' or ''XX.222.333.444. 55' for example.  This should also be set as false. (I edited the question) You also know a nice way to do this?

Comment: Ah I see the '$' and '^' sign already make this happen.

Comment: yes, `^` specify the beginning of the text and `$` specify the end.